# Form processing getting Null Pointer Exception?

Tags: java, google-app-engine, jsp, servlets

I want to process this forms field with jsp:

```
<div class="control-group">

                                                <!-- Text input-->
                                                <label class="control-label" for="input01">Email:</label>
                                                <div class="controls">
                                                    <input name="email" placeholder="email"
                                                        class="input-xlarge" type="text"
                                                        value="<%=request.getParameter("email")%>">
                                                </div>
                                            </div>
                                            <div class="control-group">
                                                <!-- Text input-->
                                                <label class="control-label" for="input01">Password:</label>
                                                <div class="controls">
                                                    <input name="password" placeholder="password"
                                                        class="input-xlarge" type="text"
                                                        value="<%=request.getParameter("password")%>">
                                                </div>
                                            </div>
```

When I press Submit I get a

> NullPointerException

thats my servlet method:

```
@Override
    public void doPost(HttpServletRequest req, HttpServletResponse resp) throws ServletException, IOException {
        logger.log(Level.INFO, "Creating User!!!");
        logger.info("Request: " +  req.toString());
        PrintWriter out = resp.getWriter();//Here I get the null Pointer exception

        String email = req.getParameter("email");
        String password = req.getParameter("password");
        logger.info(email + password);
        try {
            user.insert(email, password);
            Log.info("Inserted: " + email + "    " + password);
        } catch (Exception e) {
            String msg = DAOUser.getErrorMessage(e);
            out.print(msg);
        }
    }
```

.

How to fix this null pointer exception?

**UPDATE**

my servlet:

```
public class DAOServletUser extends HttpServlet {

    private static final long serialVersionUID = 6820994892755862282L;

    private static final Logger logger = Logger.getLogger(DAOServletUser.class.getCanonicalName());
    /**
     * Get the entities in JSON format.
     */

    public DAOServletUser() {
        super();
    }

    public IDAOUser user;

    /**
     * Create the entity and persist it.
     */
    @Override
    public void doPost(HttpServletRequest req, HttpServletResponse resp) throws ServletException, IOException {
        logger.log(Level.INFO, "Creating User!!!");
        logger.info("Request: " +  req.toString());

        if(resp==null) {
            System.out.println("Respond is NULL!!!");
        }

        PrintWriter out = resp.getWriter();//Here I get the null Pointer exception



        String email = req.getParameter("email");

        if(email==null) {
            System.out.println("email is null");
        } else {
            System.out.println("email is NOT null");
        }
        String password = req.getParameter("password");
        if(password==null) {
            System.out.println("password is null");
        } else {
            System.out.println("password is NOT null");
        }
        logger.info(email + "::" + password);
        try {
            user.insert(email, password);
            Log.info("Inserted: " + email + "    " + password);
        } catch (Exception e) {
            String msg = DAOUser.getErrorMessage(e);
            out.print(msg);
        }
    }
```

Comment: can you give exact errors message (stracktrace perhaps) ? its hard to tell exactly what the problem is

Comment: Tell us which line is throwing the error - the stack trace of the exception will have the info

Comment: Sorry guys there is no stacktrace. I only get a page where there is `Error:java.lang.NullPointerException`

Comment: What is `user`? That might be null.

Comment: user is `public IDAOUser user;`, it is simply the connector to the `DAO`

Comment: Is it instantiated? And have you checked that email and password aren't null?

Comment: How to check if email and passoword are wrong. Is there a possible way to print the jsp?

Comment: Just do a null check in your `doPost`.

Comment: After you've done `String email = req.getParameter("email");`, do `if (email == null)` and do some different handling for the request. `req.getParameter()` returns null if it finds no parameter.

Comment: You can find the stacktrace in your AppEngine logs: Go to http://appengine.google.com, select your app, then click on Logs in the left-hand menu.

Comment: Also, you should log the Exception in your catch block. By just printing an error message to the user, you won't get enough data to actual figure out what went wrong.

Comment: @PhilippReichart i looked into the `http://localhost:8888/_ah/admin/` however I haven`t find the logs...

Comment: email and password is not null! What is null then?

Comment: @maximus My bad, I assumed your app was running on AppEngine -- the local dev server doesn't have any UI for logs. What's the output in the console where you run the dev server? Please add any output to the question, not into a comment.

Comment: Thx for your response! However, I only get `Error:java.lang.NullPointerException`. I also added my whole servlet which I am using...

Comment: `user` is null and you try to call `insert()` on it, that's why you get NPE. You have to instantiate it.

Comment: @SotiriosDelimanolis thx for your answer!!! However, I am a little bit confused at the moment. Would you be so kind to post how to instantiate an Interface?(pls write it as an answer, so that I can accept it!)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I'm assuming `IDAOUser` is an interface. To implement an interface in Java, you use the `implements` keyword at class level like so:

```
public class DaoUserImpl implements IDAOUser {
    public void insert(String email, String password) {
        // your code for inserting goes here
    }
}
```

In your servlet class, instead of

```
public IDAOUser user;
```

instantiate it like this (using the `new` keyword)

```
public IDAOUser user = new DaoUserImpl();
```

You can then call `user.insert(email,password)` on an object that is not `null`.

You have to be careful for multithreading problems that may arise with this solution though, if DaoUserImpl is using shared instance data. You might want one instance of your class per request.